# Import data via the client library in Apache Marmotta

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-8, apache-marmotta

I am trying to use this **code**:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.utpl.marmotta.prueba;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import org.apache.marmotta.client.ClientConfiguration;
import org.apache.marmotta.client.clients.ImportClient;
import org.apache.marmotta.client.exception.MarmottaClientException;
import org.openrdf.rio.RDFFormat;
import org.openrdf.rio.Rio;

/**
 *
 * @author Efren
 */
public class importador {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, MarmottaClientException, URISyntaxException {
        String path = "C:\\Users\\Efren\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\metano/Recolecion.rdf";
        String context = "http://example.org/context1";
        ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration("http://localhost:8080/");
        configuration.setMarmottaContext(context);
        ImportClient importClient = new ImportClient(configuration);
        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            RDFFormat format = Rio.getParserFormatForFileName(path);
            importClient.uploadDataset(is, format.getDefaultMIMEType());
        } catch (MarmottaClientException ex) {

            System.out.println("Se ah producido un error con la carga del archivo");
        }
    }
}
```

**But when I try to run it it shows this message:**

```
cd C:\Users\Efren\Documents\NetBeansProjects\prueba; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_80" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.utpl.marmotta.prueba.importador\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_80\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-cos.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building prueba 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ prueba ---
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/marmotta/client/exception/MarmottaClientException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.marmotta.client.exception.MarmottaClientException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
Exception in thread "main" [INFO] NETBEANS-ExecEvent:{"mojo":{"id":"org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1","impl":"org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo","source":"CLI","urls":["file:\/C:\/Users\/Efren\/.m2\/repository\/org\/codehaus\/mojo\/exec-maven-plugin\/1.2.1\/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Efren\/.m2\/repository\/org\/apache\/maven\/reporting\/maven-reporting-api\/2.0.6\/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Efren\/.m2\/repository\/org\/apache\/maven\/doxia\/doxia-sink-api\/1.0-alpha-7\/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Efren\/.m2\/repository\/commons-cli\/commons-cli\/1.0\/commons-cli-1.0.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Efren\/.m2\/repository\/org\/codehaus\/plexus\/plexus-interactivity-api\/1.0-alpha-4\/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Efren\/.m2\/repository\/org\/codehaus\/plexus\/plexus-utils\/2.0.5\/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar","file:\/C:\/Users\/Efren\/.m2\/repository\/org\/apache\/commons\/commons-exec\/1.1\/commons-exec-1.1.jar"],"execId":"default-cli","goal":"exec"},"exc":{"msg":"Q29tbWFuZCBleGVjdXRpb24gZmFpbGVkLg=="},"type":"MojoFailed"}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.156s
Finished at: Tue Aug 04 19:58:00 COT 2015
Final Memory: 6M/122M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project prueba: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**This is My POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.utpl.marmotta</groupId>
<artifactId>prueba</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.marmotta</groupId>
        <artifactId>marmotta-client-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: Include the relevant section of your POM please.  Also, have a look at your `.m2` folder to see if you can find the Marmotta dependency.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is my POM and can you explain me more about .m2 folder ?

Comment: Look at `C:\Users\efren\.m2\repository` and try to find the Marlotta JAR files.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen.. i found all JAR files, and sorry for the way that i put de pom code. I don´t have so much experience using of stackoverflow

Comment: @manetsus can you help me to edit the Question please ?